# How can I get the color of pixels in my image (load grey)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using this code to print the intensity of OpenCV Mat pixels. However, I am getting character printed on the console instead of values between 0 and 250:

```
image1 = imread(nameJpg, 0);
image2 = imread(lastJpg, 0);
for (int j = 0; j < image1.rows-10; j += 1){
    for (int i = 0; i < image1.cols-10; i += 1) {
        std::cout << "" << image1.at<uchar>(i, j) << "    " <<i mage1.at<uchar>(i, j)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what have you tried as a [mcve].

Comment: do image 1 and 2 have the same size?

Comment: Ok what is not working? do you get an error message?

Comment: when I ran it I got bug and the console printed me chars instead numbers from 0 to 255

Comment: (u)char is printed as a character, cast it to a number type like  short or int instead to print numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to cast it to int, such as:

`(int)image.at<uchar>(i, j)`

You can test this by referring to the [ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/).

**Edit**

The source of the bug you're mentioning is from how you access the pixel. i should be for the rows, and j for the columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
        cout << (int)src.at<uchar>(i, j) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In gray image, the pixel intensity is between 0 and 255 not 250.

If you mean that you want to get the value of a certain pixel, you may use this:

```
auto image=cv::imread(path,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
auto pixel_value=image.at<uchar>(row_idx,col_idx);
```

**After OP's edit:**

If you want to get number instead of character while printing, use this instead:

```
auto pixel_value= static_cast<unsigned int>(image.at<uchar>(row_idx,col_idx));
```

Comment: it's give me the error: syntax error: identifier 'unsienged'

Comment: maybe didn't have me the correct include? what is the include?

Comment: "unsienged" was a typo .. it is "unsigned"